# Propagate CMake target definition to linked library

Tags: cmake

I have a project with multiple targets `release` and `test` that is linked against a static library which may be compiled with a `TEST` macro.

Say I want my `release` target to be built without the `TEST` macro and the `test` target to be built with that macro defined but that macro has to propagate to the linked-against library.

In my main `CMakeLists.txt` I have created the targets and defined that macro using `target_compile_definitions(mytest PUBLIC TEST)` but obviously the library `core` is not recognizing it.

The project tree is as follows:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── core
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── inc
│   │   ├── core_comp1.h
│   │   └── core_comp2.h
│   └── src
│       ├── core_comp1.c
│       └── core_comp2.c
├── lib
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── inc
│   │   ├── ext_comp1.h
│   │   └── ext_comp2.h
│   └── src
│       ├── ext_comp1.c
│       └── ext_comp2.c
├── main.c
├── README.md
└── test.c
```

The root `./CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(cmake_test)

# add the subdirectories
add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(lib)

# define my targets
set(MY_TARGETS myexe mytest)

# create and link against the libs
foreach(target ${MY_TARGETS})
    add_executable(${target})
    target_link_libraries(${target} PRIVATE core ext)
endforeach(target ${MY_TARGETS})

# add target specific sources
target_sources(myexe  PRIVATE main.c)
target_sources(mytest PRIVATE test.c)

# define the TEST macro for mytest
target_compile_definitions(mytest PUBLIC TEST)
```

The `./core/CMakeLists.txt` library folder has:

```
add_library(core
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/core_comp1.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/core_comp2.c
)

target_include_directories(core PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
)

target_link_libraries(core PRIVATE ext)
```

The output of `myexe`, the `release target` is correct:

```
Running the release executable
Original core_comp1_display
```

While that of `mytest` is not correct:

```
Running the test executable
Original core_comp1_display
```

It should be:

```
Running the test executable
Test core_comp1_display
```

I have pushed the project to GitLab at [cmake-library-test](https://gitlab.com/mahmoud.mahdi.93/cmake-library-test)

The compilation of the `myexe` target gives the follows:

```
[build] [9/12   8% :: 0.032] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp2.c
[build] [9/12  16% :: 0.034] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp2.c
[build] [9/12  25% :: 0.039] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp2.c.o -MF lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp2.c.o.d -o lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp2.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp2.c
[build] [9/12  33% :: 0.041] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp1.c.o -MF lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp1.c.o.d -o lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp1.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp1.c
[build] [10/12  41% :: 0.043] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp1.c
[build] [10/12  50% :: 0.046] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../core/inc -g -MD -MT core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp2.c.o -MF core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp2.c.o.d -o core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp2.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp2.c
[build] [10/12  58% :: 0.049] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../core/inc -g -MD -MT core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp1.c.o -MF core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp1.c.o.d -o core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp1.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp1.c
[build] [11/12  66% :: 0.054] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/main.c.o -c ../../main.c
[build] [11/12  75% :: 0.058] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp1.c
[build] [11/12  83% :: 0.110] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f lib/libmylib.a && /usr/bin/ar qc lib/libmylib.a  lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp1.c.o lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp2.c.o && /usr/bin/ranlib lib/libmylib.a && :
[build] [11/12  91% :: 0.119] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f core/libcore.a && /usr/bin/ar qc core/libcore.a  core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp1.c.o core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp2.c.o && /usr/bin/ranlib core/libcore.a && :
[build] [12/12 100% :: 0.147] : && /usr/bin/gcc -g  CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/main.c.o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o -o myexe  core/libcore.a  lib/libmylib.a && :
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

Whereas the compilation of `mytest` give:

```
[build] [9/12   8% :: 0.035] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../core/inc -g -MD -MT core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp2.c.o -MF core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp2.c.o.d -o core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp2.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp2.c
[build] [9/12  16% :: 0.045] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp1.c
[build] [9/12  25% :: 0.047] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp2.c
[build] [9/12  33% :: 0.049] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp2.c
[build] [9/12  41% :: 0.049] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../core/inc -g -MD -MT core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp1.c.o -MF core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp1.c.o.d -o core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp1.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp1.c
[build] [10/12  50% :: 0.052] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/test.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/test.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/test.c.o -c ../../test.c
[build] [10/12  58% :: 0.056] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp1.c
[build] [10/12  66% :: 0.065] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp2.c.o -MF lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp2.c.o.d -o lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp2.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp2.c
[build] [10/12  75% :: 0.069] /usr/bin/gcc  -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp1.c.o -MF lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp1.c.o.d -o lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp1.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp1.c
[build] [11/12  83% :: 0.127] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f core/libcore.a && /usr/bin/ar qc core/libcore.a  core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp1.c.o core/CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/core_comp2.c.o && /usr/bin/ranlib core/libcore.a && :
[build] [11/12  91% :: 0.139] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f lib/libmylib.a && /usr/bin/ar qc lib/libmylib.a  lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp1.c.o lib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/ext_comp2.c.o && /usr/bin/ranlib lib/libmylib.a && :
[build] [12/12 100% :: 0.168] : && /usr/bin/gcc -g  CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/test.c.o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o -o mytest  core/libcore.a  lib/libmylib.a && :
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

It is clear that `core_comp*.c` and `ext_comp*.c` were compiled without -DTEST

Using the suggested `INTERFACE` keyword, the flag `-DTEST` is passed into all files and the compilation is as follows:

```
[build] [5/6  16% :: 0.024] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp2.c
[build] [5/6  33% :: 0.025] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp2.c
[build] [5/6  50% :: 0.038] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o -c ../../lib/src/ext_comp1.c
[build] [5/6  66% :: 0.041] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o -c ../../core/src/core_comp1.c
[build] [5/6  83% :: 0.058] /usr/bin/gcc -DTEST -I../../core/inc -I../../lib/inc -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/test.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/test.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/test.c.o -c ../../test.c
[build] [6/6 100% :: 0.134] : && /usr/bin/gcc -g  CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/test.c.o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp1.c.o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/core/src/core_comp2.c.o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp1.c.o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/lib/src/ext_comp2.c.o -o mytest   && :
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

The libraries `core` and `mylib` are now transparent and the targets `myexe` and `mytest` are actually considering the libraries sources are 'their'

Comment: @KamilCuk using `target_link_libraries(core PRIVATE mytest)` will cause an error `Attempt to add link library "mytest" to target "core" which is not built in this directory`

Comment: It is **requirement** of the Stack Overflow that relevant code should be **included** into the **question post**, not just *linked*. Please, add your code (`CMakeLists.txt` at least) into the question post. See also [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev noted, I added the 2 major `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Well, the code you show is definitely not sufficient for understand the problem, but according to the linked repo, the lines `Original core_comp1_display` and `Test core_comp1_display` are output by the `core` library dependent on the value of `TEST` macro. You link `core` library to both `test` and `release` executables and want the library to output **different** lines. This is simply not possible: Your `core` library is **built once**, so only a **single output** is possible. This output is determined when you build the library itself, not when you link with it.

Comment: You may create **separate libraries** (say `core_test` and `core_release`) and link them into `test` and `release` correspondingly. Or you may add a parameter to the `core_comp1_display` function which prints the lines, so `test` and `release` executables could be able to call this function with different parameters. Instead of parameter to the function, you may create some variable in `core` library and give `test` and `release` a way to set a value for this variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know I can do that and it may be the only solution but I am looking for some genius solutions usin CMake features I might not know about

Comment: Whatever features CMake have, it just **calls the compiler** for create a library/executable. A compiler cannot build a single library which prints different strings. So CMake cannot do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve similar behavior is to use an interface library and add the source files to the interface library via [target_sources()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html).

This doesn't actually propagate the definition down to the library, instead it brings the sources up to the consuming targets.  One would want to be sure and only depend on this library via `PRIVATE` or else the sources would get compiled for each subsequent dependent.

I wouldn't encourage this solution, but I've had need of it before, so thought I would share.

`./CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(example)

add_subdirectory(lib)

add_executable(my_exe main.c)
target_link_libraries(my_exe PRIVATE my_lib) 

add_executable(my_test main.c)
target_link_libraries(my_test PRIVATE my_lib) 
target_compile_definitions(my_test PRIVATE TEST)
```

`./main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * get_string();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("The message is \"%s\"\n", get_string());
    return 0;
}
```

`lib/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_library(my_lib INTERFACE)
target_sources(my_lib INTERFACE message.c)
```

`lib/message.c`

```
#ifdef TEST
const char * get_string(){
    return "The test string";
}
#else
const char * get_string(){
    return "The normal string";
}
#endif
```

Comment: Your idea works !
The only caveat is that they are not treated as libraries anymore and the sources are part of the targets utilizing the interface libraries

Comment: > The only caveat is that they are not treated as libraries anymore and the sources are part of the targets utilizing the interface libraries

Correct it is no longer a stand alone library.  You could use an intermediate library for each version, but if you go that route, you are probably better off doing what Tsyvarev suggested and just make 2 libraries from the get go.
If you find yourself using this solution a lot, it might be worth investing in other methods of making code testable.